# ShowcaseView highlights wrong item

Tags: android, showcaseview

I use ShowcaseView like this:

```
ActionItemTarget target = new ActionItemTarget(this, R.id.menu_search);

ShowcaseView sv = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this, true)
                .setTarget(target)
                .setContentText("Press this to search")
                .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme)
                .build();
```

But when I start app the first, ShowcaseView highlights home button. When I try to start app again, correct ActionBar item is showcased.
My app doesn't use compatibility libraries like ActionbarSherlock.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "start app again". Do you force close it and open it or you reopen it calling onPause + onResume? Also when are you calling this code? Because `R.id.menu_search` may not be available yet at that time

Comment: @PedroOliveira I was calling it in onCreate(). Obviously that's a wrong place.

Comment: The best place to use this code would be on onCreateOptionsMenu and even there `R.id.menu_search` is not pointing to a view because it hasn't been inflated yet so you will have to find a way to do that there without using the id.

Comment: @PedroOliveira maybe you can post an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested:

The problem is that you are trying to retrieve an id for a view that is not in the hierarchy yet. According to the activity view cycle the menu is only created after `onCreate`. The best solution is to use `onCreateOptionsMenu` but even here `R.id.menu_search` will not return a valid id because the menu hasn't been created yet. Since the order of events has changed in API lvl 16 I suggest you hack it a little bit. You can create a handler on your `onCreate()` and execute a postDelayed runable. The code will be executed after the menu has been designed. On that runable you can retrieve the view for `R.id.menu_search` and highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to present sample code here:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
            .withMaterialShowcase()
            .setTarget(new ToolbarActionItemTarget(this.toolbar, R.id.menu_search))
            .setContentText("Here's how to highlight items on a toolbar")
            .build()
            .show();

    return true;
}
```

Note: **toolbar** declare as member of the class.